# JQuery slideUp() / slideDown() causes clicked element to be hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, slide

I have a simple list structure looking like this

```
<ul class="list">
  <li id="li1"></li>
  <li><ul id="ul1"></ul></li>

  <li id="li2"></li>
  <li><ul id="ul2"></ul></li>

  <li id="li3"></li>
  <li><ul id="ul3"></ul></li>

  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

and

```
ul li ul {display: none;}
```

and

```
$(".list li").click(function(){
  $(".list li ul).slideUp();
  $("#ul" + $(this).attr("id").substr(2)).slideDown();
});
```

which does exactly what I want, it closes all opened `ul`s when clicking another `li` to show up (this is the minified version, obvious I am checking if it is already visible etc.).

The problem however is following: let's assume these `ul ul`s have contents higher than a window height and that we have opened the second last one. To look at the last one, we scroll to the bottom and click the last `li`. Now since the now closing `ul` was bigger than a window height, the clicked `li` gets pulled up because of the `slideDown()`-animation, and as a result the clicked `li` disappears from the viewport. Is there any solution to handle this using `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`? The goal would be that the window scrolling animation gets stopped when the click `li` reaches something like `top:50px`, but in the same time the slideUp() animation must terminate and close the ul from before.

Comment: FYI your HTML is invalid. `ul` cannot be a child of another `ul`, only `li`

Comment: my fault, corrected code, question remains

Comment: Have you considered doing this in pure CSS? You can use the slidedown effect using transitions. This way within your LI you can have say a div for the dropdown and then if the hover on the LI binds the showing of the element you wont have an issue with the viewport.

Comment: Also instead of doing: $("#ul" + $(this).attr("id").substr(2)).slideDown(); why not just do $(this).find('div').slideDown(); and have a div that is the contents of your UL instead. Much cleaner.

Comment: How about animating expansion that exceeds the viewport bottom edge will rectify itself by scrolling so that the origin of click is at the top of viewport?

Comment: @zer00ne that is exactly what I want to do, but I was not able to customize the slideDown effect, even with "step: function"

Comment: @ValentinoRu If you don't mind using jQuery and jQueryUI, I can help otherwise it's way to much work to be worth the time.